# what if the hessian of the Lagrangian is null?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, hessian-matrix

In a non-linear optimization problem, suppose given a candidate solution $x*$, we want to verify second order sufficient conditions of optimality but the Hessian of the Lagrangian of the problem at $x*$ is null.

What could we conclude in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You conclude nothing. For instance, if

- $f(x,y)=x^4+y^4$;
- $g(x,y)=x^3+y^3$;
- $h(x,y)=-x^4-y^2$

then, in each case, $(0,0)$ is a critical point and the Hessian at $(0,0)$ is the null matrix. But $(0,0)$ is

- the point at which $f$ attains its absolute minimum;
- a saddle point of $g$;
- the point at which $h$ attains its absolute maximum.

Comment: I was talking about a nonlinear programming. I mean an optimization problem with constraints.

Comment: @yasare Then consider my examples in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the constraint that $z=0$. For instance, consider $f(x,y,z,)=x^4+y^4$ and the problem of finding the maximum and the minimum of $f$ in the plane $z=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. @José Carlos Santos